# How to disable the range slider when the checkbox is checked in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I want my range slider is disabled when the checkbox is checked using jquery.If check box is unchecked then range slider want to be enable.My code is,

```
$(document).on('change','#checkbox6b',function()
{
    if("input[name='responsive']:checked")
    {
      /* code */
    }
    else
    {
      /* code */
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please include your html

Comment: You can use passing enable/disable in slider function `$('#slider1').slider('disable');` to enable `$('#slider1').slider('enable');`

Comment: Explain your range slider `HTML` and `jQuery`.

Comment: It's working now..Thanks @PankajMakwana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call properties `disable` and `enable` on your range slider.

Please replace the id with your ranger's HTML ID attribute.

```
$(document).on('change','#checkbox6b',function()
{
    if($("input[name='responsive']:checked"))
    {
      $('#YOUR-SLIDER-ID').slider('disable');
    }
    else
    {
      $('#YOUR-SLIDER-ID').slider('enable');
    }
});
```

Comment: `"input[name='responsive']:checked"` should be $("input[name='responsive']:checked") or you can just use `$(this).is(":checked")`

Comment: @RiazLaskar, thanks for the update. I have corrected my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the range slider's disabled/enabled state using jQuery's [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method and use the checkbox as value:

```
$(document).on('change', '#checkbox6b', function() {
  $(<your-range-slider>).prop('disabled', $('input[name='responsive']').is(':checked'));
});
```